# Send an email when message goes into Azure Service Bus dead letter queue

Tags: .net, azureservicebus

Is it possible to trigger an email at the point a message gets sent to Azure Service Bus dead letter queue after too many failed attempts? Can it be configured through a tool or is there an event to hook up to?

Answer (score 0):

You can try create an Azure App Service Workflow with Azure Service Bus Connector and Sendgrid. It seems to be a way.

https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-pt/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-azureservicebus/

And in [English](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-azureservicebus/)